# How do enable internal Azure Services for SQL Azure in c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, windows-firewall

How do I enable **allowed services : WINDOWS AZURE SERVICES** as seen in the Management Portal in c#?

```
        _client = new SqlManagementClient(GetSubscriptionCredentials());

        var result = _client.Servers.CreateAsync(new ServerCreateParameters
        {
            AdministratorUserName = _config.ServerUserName,
            AdministratorPassword = _config.ServerPassword,
            Location = _config.Location,
            Version = "12.0"
        }, CancellationToken.None).Result;

        var sqlServerName = result.ServerName;

        // This will go away once we can enable the Azure internal firewall settings == Yes
        var ipAddress = _firewallManagement.GetPublicIP();
        var firewall = _client.FirewallRules.Create(sqlServerName, new FirewallRuleCreateParameters("Server", ipAddress, ipAddress));
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add 0.0.0.0 as start_ip_address and end_ip_address like the T-SQL below to sys.firewall_rules

```
exec sp_set_firewall_rule N'MicrosoftServices','0.0.0.0','0.0.0.0'
```

Don't mind the 0.0.0.0 range, SQL Azure knows it is only for Azure IPs in your subscription.

```
select * from sys.firewall_rules

id  name    start_ip_address    end_ip_address  create_date modify_date
7   MicrosoftService    0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 2015-07-29 13:34:55.790 2015-07-29 13:34:55.790
```

**Azure SQL Database Firewall**

> When an application from Azure attempts to connect to your database
>   server, the firewall verifies that Azure connections are allowed. A
>   firewall setting with starting and ending address equal to 0.0.0.0
>   indicates these connections are allowed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee621782.aspx#ConnectingFromAzure

**Adding and Deleting SQL Azure firewall rules programmatically**

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/adding-and-deleting-sql-azure-firewall-rules-programmatically/

```
public void AddFirewallRule(FirewallRule rule)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "sp_set_firewall_rule";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = rule.Name;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@start_ip_address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rule.startIPAddress.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@end_ip_address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rule.endIPAdress.ToString();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `var azureFirewall = _client.FirewallRules.Create(sqlServerName, new      FirewallRuleCreateParameters("MicrosoftServices", "0.0.0.0", "0.0.0.0"));`

Answer (score -1):

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-client-library/ has the latest way of doing this